# Why are there many folders for Java in Ubuntu?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, javac

I'm a newbie at java development, but if something always made me very confused was this JDK x JRE difference.

Now I want to understand what is installed in each folder that contains Java code

For example, there is this folder:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/
```

And there is a folder called JRE inside of it. Is that the JRE?

If so, where is the JDK installed? Is there a folder for that, or the source is is split in existing folders?

If I run `whereis java` it prints

```
/usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

And if I run `which java` it says

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Can someone give me a short explanation about this?

Comment: check what it prints, check the files

Comment: @passion what you mean?

Comment: check the printed files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is common in Unux to install an application in its own directory. This makes management easier. The downside is your shell won't find it there unless you add it to the PATH or add a link to it in a common directory as in the case of java.

In your case you can find the JDK with

```
which javac
```

However unless you have installed it you probably don't have it.

There is two ways to check while a file or directory has been configured.  You can do

```
ls -ld /usr/bin/java
```

or

```
file /usr/bin/java
```

Note: `java` is the name of the package AND the name of the program in that package which is why it can appear more than once.

BTW `/usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz` is for the manual or "man" page for Java.